# "Of" with the words color, gender, size

Tags: prepositions

Do we need of in the following:

> This room is of a comfortable size. or This room is a comfortable
> size.
>
> This word is of a masculine gender. or  This word is a masculine
> gender.
>
> This car is of a red color. or This car is a red color.

Any logic?

Comment: Interesting one. It seems to depend on the adjective - none of the provided examples work and seem natural (they seem to imply that a car is *itself* a color, etc., akin to *John is a doctor*), but then why does it work for eg. *This car is a certain color*, *This room is the same size*, etc.?

Comment: @MaciejStachowski Some good points. I think a key point is the redundancy; there's just no need to say "red color" or "masculine gender" instead of "red" or "masculine", so it sounds unnatural. But I'm not sure how best to address that within the framework of the question.

Comment: "This word is of _the_ masculine gender." The word itself isn't a gender, and each language has a fixed number of (grammatical) genders, with only one being masculine.

Comment: @ the-baby-is-you redundancy is a separate issue. Being redundant doesn't mean being grammatically wrong.

Comment: @Kate Bunting OK, but a room is not a size as such as well. But "this room is a comfortable size" is correct, nevertheless.

Comment: True - I was just making a point about that particular example.